# What’s the grammatical role of "for you" in "I am waiting for you"?

Tags: terminology, grammatical-roles

What is the grammatical role of "for you" in "I am waiting for you"? Is it a direct object, a prepositional phrase or what? Functionally, it seems to be of an object, as "you" in "I love you", but I am not sure how English labels objects of verbs which require a preposition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grammatical role of *for you* in

1. I am waiting **for you**.

is that it is an  optional [***argument***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(linguistics)#Arguments_vs._adjuncts) to the verb. It is not an [***adjunct***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)). It just happens to be a prepositional argument, not a core argument like subjects and objects are.

It’s also an argument here:

2. She came looking **for you**.
3. I made a cake **for you**.

If in #2 *for you* seems more obviously an argument than it does in #3, remember that #3 is just the dative alternation for the ditransitive two-object version:

4. I made you a cake.

Answer (score 1):

you is an object in the prepostional phrase "for you"

wait is an intransitive verb so it can not take an object

we can not say I am waiting you

but await is a transitive verb which takes an object

we can say that I am awaiting you

Comment: Actually, "waiting" is transitive in a number of contexts.

Comment: I don't see where you’ve answered the question asked. The question isn't about *you*. It's about the grammatical role played by *for you* in the provided sentence. Plus as @HotLicks mentioned, “transitivity happens”: *You just wait your turn, you! You either wait this one out or else it’s back to waiting tables again, kid.*

Comment: @tchrist  i answered that it was a prepositional phrase.I do not have as much lingjuistic terminology and knowledge as you have

Comment: @tchrist  i answered that it was a prepositional phrase.I do not have as much lingjuistic terminology and knowledge as you have